# Delphi fmx tabcontrol event before new tab is displayed

Tags: delphi, onchange, tabcontrol, firemonkey

I'm writing a FMX program in Delphi XE7 for Windows. I'm using TabControl. I need to show the message in active tab, when another tabitem is clicked.

Problem is that OnClick of TabItem, or OnChange of TabControl first displays a new tab and then shows me a message..and I need to get message before displaying a new tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear how you display the message "*in active tab*" and why you want to show it **in** the tab you are just about to leave.

If you mean that you want to show a message using ShowMessage() before the tab change takes place you can do it in TTabItem OnMouseDown:

```
procedure TForm4.TabItem2MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  ShowMessage('TabItem2MouseDown, Active tab: '+TabControl1.ActiveTab.Name);
end;
```

When TabItem1 is active and TabItem2 is clicked, the above code shows

> TabItem2MouseDown, Active tab: TabItem1

and when you dismiss the message box the tab change takes place.

Comment: Thank you, i will try this. In different tabs i have infromation from different tables from database, so i need to show message dialog if some changes have been made, to confirm them defore leaving the tab :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use the accept solution above.  Unfortunately, in Delphi Berlin FMX, by the time the MouseDown event occurs, the ActiveTab has already changed.

For anyone else looking for a solution, see [Delphi can Fire monkey TTabControl replicate VCL TPageControl.OnChanging event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877118/delphi-can-fire-monkey-ttabcontrol-replicate-vcl-tpagecontrol-onchanging-event) as a possibility.