# Firemonkey TTabControl: adding tab items

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tabcontrol, tabitem

I've added a `TTabItem`with this simple code but it does not compile:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.TabControl;

type
  TTabItem = class(FMX.TabControl.TTabItem)
    procedure MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single); override;
  end;

  TTabControl = class(FMX.TabControl.TTabControl)
    function GetTabIndex : integer;
    public
    procedure SetTabIndexv2(const Value: Integer);
    property TabIndex: Integer read GetTabIndex write SetTabIndexv2 default -1;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    tbc1: TTabControl;
    TabItem1: TTabItem;
    TabItem2: TTabItem;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

{ TTabItem }

procedure TTabItem.MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Single);
begin
  if (self.TabControl.ActiveTab <> self) and
     ((Button = TMouseButton.mbLeft) or (ssDouble in Shift)) then begin
    MessageDlg('[Tab Item] do you want to do this?', System.UITypes.TMsgDlgType.mtInformation,
      [System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbYes, System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbNo], 0, procedure (const AResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      begin
        case AResult of
          mrYes: self.TabControl.ActiveTab := self;
          mrNo:;
        end;
      end;
    end);
  end else begin
    inherited;
  end;
end;

{ TTabControl }

function TTabControl.GetTabIndex: integer;
begin
 result := FMX.TabControl.TTabControl(Self).TabIndex;
end;

procedure TTabControl.SetTabIndexv2(const Value: Integer);
begin
  if self.TabIndex <> value then begin
    MessageDlg('[tabcontrol] do you want to do this?', System.UITypes.TMsgDlgType.mtInformation,
      [System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbYes, System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbNo], 0, procedure (const AResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      begin
        case AResult of
        mrYes: begin
                 FMX.TabControl.TTabControl(Self).TabIndex := value;
               end;
        mrNo :  ;
        end;
      end;
    end);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if tbc1.TabIndex = 0 then
    tbc1.TabIndex := 1
  else
    tbc1.TabIndex := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  tbitem: TTabItem;
begin
  tbitem := tbc1.Add( ); //Here Error !!!
end;

end.
```

> [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(106): E2010 Incompatible types: 'Unit1.TTabItem' and 'FMX.TabControl.TTabItem'

[Can Firemonkey TTabControl replicate VCL TPageControl.OnChanging event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877118/delphi-can-fire-monkey-ttabcontrol-replicate-vcl-tpagecontrol-onchanging-event/47593494#47593494)

Comment: Maybe you have duplicate TTabItem class declaration in your Unit1...

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I can not understand which part is wrong.

thank you.

Comment: What does your declaration of `Unit1.TTabItem` look like? You should generally show sufficient context of the problem. 4 lines with no context is usually just a waste of time.

Comment: Can you look now?

Comment: The `Unit1.TTabItem` is a different type identity than the returned by `tbc1.Add()`. You can type cast it like: `tbItem := TTabItem(tbc1.Add());`

Comment: Hi Tom Thanks.

Unfortunately this typecast does not work correctly
because the OnMouseDown events do not occur.

In Design time mode I did not have to set anything.

thank you

Comment: Where is no need to declare a new class for catching MouseDown event. Just write OnMouseDown procedure and assign it to every TabItem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Unfortunately you need yes because in delphi 10.2.1 the onmousedown event occurs after the onchange event

I need to capture before changing the tab.

thank you

Comment: [Documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.TabControl.TTabControl.Add) states you need to provide a `TTabClass` for `TTabControl.Add` function if you want to specify the class of the created object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nearly there.

```
procedure TForm15.ButtonRandomSeedClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  tbitem: TTabItem;
begin
  tbitem := TabControl1.Add( TTabItem ) as TTabItem; //<<<<< Change 1
  tbItem.Text := 'Tab ' + IntToStr( TabControl1.TabCount );
end;

procedure TForm15.TabItem1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
var
  tbitem: TTabItem;
begin
  tbitem := (Sender as TTabItem);  // <<<<<<this change for testing only  
  if (tbItem <> TabControl1.ActiveTab) and
     ((Button = TMouseButton.mbLeft) or (ssDouble in Shift)) then begin
    MessageDlg('[Tab Item] do you want to do this?', System.UITypes.TMsgDlgType.mtInformation,
      [System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbYes, System.UITypes.TMsgDlgBtn.mbNo], 0, procedure (const AResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      begin
        case AResult of
          mrYes: TabControl1.ActiveTab := (Sender as TTabItem);
          mrNo:;
        end;
      end;
    end);
  end else begin
    inherited;
  end;

end;
```

works as you want. (My names are different to yours)

Answer (score 1):

With this modification to your code, a popup asking 'do you want to do this' is shown whenever a tab is about to be selected.

```
procedure TForm22.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  tbitem: TTabItem;
begin
//  tbitem := tbc1.Add( ); //Here Error !!!
  tbItem := TTabItem(tbc1.Add(TTabItem));
  tbitem.Text := 'Item '+tbitem.Index.ToString();
end;
```

The second line I added only to see some text in the tabs.

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Thank you again for your generosity.

God bless you have a wonderful day.